# Given a folder of Java files, is there an Eclipse plugin to draw UML class diagrams?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, class-diagram

The title says it all. Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the 2 valid free Eclipse plugins I know about regarding UML class diagrams:

---

- **[ObjectAidUML](http://www.objectaid.com/)**

> It uses the UML notation to show a graphical representation of existing code that is as accurate and up-to-date as your text editor, while being very easy to use.

The recommended way is a remote Eclipse update site with the following information:

```
Name: ObjectAid UML Explorer
URL: http://www.objectaid.com
```

[image: http://www.objectaid.com/static/images/drag-class-on-diagram.png]

---

- [**eUML2**](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/)

It has a free version which includes class diagrams.

[image: http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/screenshots/class_diagram_small.png]

Comment: Off course, zvikico (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2823/zvikico) would want me to mention the excellent nWire (http://www.nwiresoftware.com/), but it is not *exactly* UML, and if it not free (although it has free trial, and free offer for bloggers (http://www.nwiresoftware.com/buy/special-offers) ;)