# Best UML plugins for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, uml

I just inherited a J2SE project and will be working on it on Eclipse. I'd like to get some diagrams out of the existing code and I'm looking for good UML plugins to use with Eclipse.

Any recommendations?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056208/given-a-folder-of-java-files-is-there-a-eclipse-pluging-to-draw-class-diagrams/2056299#2056299

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, I think your best bet isn't an Eclipse plugin at all, but Enterprise Architect by Sparx Systems. Its cost is reasonable ([$200-300 US for the Professional version](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/purchase.html)), and it can reverse engineer an existing code base into UML. I've used it on several projects, and have found it invaluable whenever I needed the 20,000-foot overview on an existing project.

Also, I haven't used its UML capabilities extensively, but MyEclipse ([for $65 US](http://www.myeclipseide.com/)) claims to have reverse-engineering capabilities as well.

Comment: Enterprise Architect is already available for $169 and afaik they also have an exlipe plugin. It is really worth it! Best Value for Price!

Comment: Defiantly worth its money. EA is so powerful. Also one of the few UML tools that is *really* capable of reverse and forward engineering, even though your projects evolve over time.

Comment: Is there any open source plugin for UML in eclipse?

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want to generate some diagrams from existing code, then I would just go for [Eclipse UML2 Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2tools).

Answer (score 5):

Remember that a list of all Eclipse UML2 compatible tools can be found here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2-Tool-Compatibility

Many of them are free and very good

Answer (score 3):

I like [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/). It is XML based which makes it very useful for diff'ing if needed.

Comment: But UMlet can't make UML from existing code or can it ?

Answer (score 2):

A year ago I tried some UML tools for Eclipse. I don't know if that has changed recently but I didn't find any good open source solution (Modelling tools are always extremely expensive) for WYSIWYG UML with Round Trip engineering (meaning changing your code will change your UML model and vice versa). I found [Omondos UML Plugin](http://www.ejb3.org/download_studio_eclipse_3.5.html) the best commercial UML Eclipse plugin. There is a trial version, too, but it's probably not a good choice if your project is short on money (a 1 developer licence is around 4000$).

Answer (score 1):

I've used Poseidon for UML in the past and found it a perfectly decent product. The same company have an eclipse plugin which claims to do (amongst other things) round trip engineering:

http://www.gentleware.com/apollo.html

It's available for $6 per month, and has a 30 day trial.