# Example of Visio + Architechture of JSF application

Tags: jsf, visio

I was asked to display the tech design of my JSF application with Visio.

Anyone has an example of uml Visio Diagram for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is actually that you don't know how to create/use/understand UML in general, then I would recommend to **learn** about it first. You could also install/use an UML plugin for/of your IDE to generate some UML in your IDE and port it to Visio.

If you're using for example Eclipse, you may find either of those topics useful (all found by [this simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uml+eclipse)):

- [From Java code to UML diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687323/from-java-code-to-uml-diagram)
- [Good free UML tool for Java/Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse)
- [Best UML plugins for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111516/best-uml-plugins-for-eclipse)
- [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)