# Is there a good plugin for generate UML from Android(Java) classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

I am looking for a good plugin for eclipse to read my Android classes and generate the UML of my android classes, with the classes diagram, the associations, inheritances. etc.

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest removing the Android tag, and adding a Java one - this question is really about geenrating UML for Java - Android vs J2xE is an implementation detail.

On that theme, there's a good discussion on tools in this thread <s>[How to generate UML diagrams (especially sequence diagrams) from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)</s> (link invalid).

[free UML sequence diagram reverse engineering eclipse plugin working out of the box - does such a thing exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470329/free-uml-sequence-diagram-reverse-engineering-eclipse-plugin-working-out-of-the)

Do you really need tight Eclipse integration? You could probably use a command-line tool and add an Ant target for it - that way you can have UML updated as part of your build process.

If you're not already using Ant, you can add support following the instructions at [Managing Projects from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

Hope this helps,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

What I did is developed the code in Eclipse and after that used Netbeans. I copy paste code in netbeans project workspace (ignore errors, its due to Android not configured in Netbeans) for this. http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetbeansUML

rohit