# How to generate sequence diagram without running the program

Tags: java, uml, sequence

I need to generate Sequence Diagram for my project.

I have made the classes, methods with proper signatures, method calls from one class to other etc., however, i cant really run the web application to get the Sequence diagram by trace since logic is yet to be implemented.

Is there any way in which i can get sequence diagrams without running the trace?

Language:Java

IDE: Eclipse

Comment: try http://argouml.tigris.org/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470329/free-uml-sequence-diagram-reverse-engineering-eclipse-plugin-working-out-of-the

Comment: hey @raddykrish i have checked diver, however, it needs me to execute my project in trace mode.I cannot execute since i havent put logic yet.My project is currently in design phase,construction hasnt started,i just a rough outline to explain the flow to my colleagues.

Comment: the subject of the question says you need a sequence diagram, diver supports static sequence diagram by selecting a method a generate a sequence. you can generate static sequence for important methods and explain your colleagues.

Comment: @raddykrish thanks buddy!!..That suggestion solved my problem.!!..how do i mark ur comment as the answer?

Comment: i can copy my comments as an answer you can accept that. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments you can use diver to generate static sequence diagrams. Diver supports static sequence diagram by selecting a method and generate a sequence. you can generate static sequence for important methods and explain your colleagues.