# UML diagrams in Eclipse (Android)

Tags: java, android

Is there any software for generating sequence or class diagrams for java code (Android) in Eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many of them: [eUML2](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/), [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/), [Object Aid](https://www.objectaid.com/) etc. Just Googling might have helped you. 
 You can read about some of the reviews <s>[How to generate UML diagrams (especially sequence diagrams) from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)</s> (invalid link) question. In addition you can also check [inFusion](http://www.intooitus.com/products/infusion),  [JUPE](http://jupe.binaervarianz.de/) and and [Class Visualizer](http://www.class-visualizer.net/faq.html). Hope this helps.

Replacement link: [free UML sequence diagram reverse engineering eclipse plugin working out of the box - does such a thing exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470329/free-uml-sequence-diagram-reverse-engineering-eclipse-plugin-working-out-of-the)